# How to replace multiple occurrences of variable in a file using sed?

Tags: shell, sed, makefile

I am already working on a script to replace value of a variable "SUBDIRS" in a Makefile from shell script.
I used below command and it works fine but exits after doing for first occurrene of "SUBDIRS" and makefile is incomplete.

```
 sed -z -i "s/\(SUBDIRS = \).*/\1$(tr '\n' ' ' < changed_fe_modules.log)\n/g" Makefile
```

Now I want to keep my Makefile as it is and only replace 3 occurrences of "SUBDIRS= abcdefgh" and update Makefile properly.

Please suggest how to just replace all 3 occurrences and keep Makefile also end to end as original.

Makefile input sample:

[image]

Makefile Desired output sample:

[image]

Right now, current command is giving me below output: it exits after first replacement and file is incomplete.

[image]

Comment: Give sample data of `Makefile` and your expected output.

Comment: @Utsav Updated my question with more details.

Comment: Why do you want to end up with the same SUBDIRS statement repeated multiple times? Whatever you're trying to do would be trivial in awk but you'd have to add concise, testable sample input and expected output (i.e. text, not photos of text!) and add the awk tag to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be very hard to do.

The reason you're seeing this behavior is that you're using the `-z` option with sed.  The `-z` option separates lines with NUL characters, not newlines.  This means the entire file (up to the first NUL character, which there isn't one here) is treated as a single "line" for the purposes of sed's pattern matching.

So this regex:

```
\(SUBDIRS = \).*
```

the `.*` here matches the entire rest of the file after the first `SUBDIRS =` match.  Then you replace the entire rest of the file with the contents of the `changed_fe_modules.log` file.  After that there's nothing left to match, so sed is done.

If your original makefile listed all the SUBDIRS on a single line, not using backslash/newline separators, it would be simple; you can just use:

```
sed -i "s/^SUBDIRS = .*/SUBDIRS = $(tr '\n' ' ' < changed_fe_modules.log)/" Makefile
```

If you have to use the backslash/newline you probably won't be able to make this change using sed.  You'll need to use something more powerful like Perl which has non-greedy matching capabilities.

*ETA*

You could also write it in plain shell:

```
new_subdirs=$(tr '\n' ' ' < changed_fe_modules.log)
line_cont=false
in_subdirs=false

while read -r line; do
    if $line_cont; then
        case $line in
            (*\\) : still continuing ;;
            (*) line_cont=false ;;
        esac
        $in_subdirs || printf '%s\n' "$line"
        continue
    fi

    case $line in
        (SUBDIRS =*)
            echo "SUBDIRS = $new_subdirs"
            in_subdirs=true ;;
        (*) printf '%s\n' "$line"
            in_subdirs=false ;;
    esac

    case $line in
        (*\\) line_cont=true ;;
    esac

done < Makefile > Makefile.new

mv -f Makefile.new Makefile
```

(note, completely untested)

Comment: Thanks for explaination. This gives lot more clarity. I will see if I can use any other language here since my rest of the script is in bash.